# can you give any asp.net control that is not rendered as html?

Tags: asp.net

hi all is there any asp.net server control that is not rendering in html page ?
for instance `<asp: TextBox runat ="server" id="Textbox1"><asp:/TextBox>` is rendered as `<input type="Text" id="textbox1"/>`?
i think you would understand my question ?

Comment: can you name any dogs that aren't an animal?

Comment: sir there are some asp control. which is not rendered in html.<asp:Literal ID="literal1" runat="server" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Literal control is not rendered unless something is added to the Text property, in which case just the contents of the Text property are rendered. Likewise, the Placeholder control only renders the controls placed in its Controls collection.

```
<asp:Literal ID="literal1" runat="server" />

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: They are both used to render things. I think he is asking for server controls that are not meant to render anything ?

Comment: Who knows what they are asking. That was my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Every class deriving from the base class `WebControl` are meant to be rendered. That base class contains essentially rendering stuff such as styles and of course, the `Render` method.

Of course you can override the `Render` method and void it, but I don't see the advantage of having a UI control that doesn't render anything.

Both `Literal` & `PlaceHolder` have been designed to render stuff, but by default, they render nothing.

Use a plain class instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess at what you're after, but maybe `<asp:HiddenField />` ?

Comment: An hidden field is rendered as HTML, but not visible in the browser window. Maybe it's what he is looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<asp:placeholder>` control.

The `<asp:panel>` produces a div but the  has no output but its great for adding controls without adding unwanted additional html